# Можно ли, используя flex с space-between, расположить последнюю строчку с привязкой слева?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

К примеру, следующие блоки:

```css
div.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
div.flex > div {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Всё бы хорошо, но последнюю строчку хочется сделать так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом это сделать? Конечно, можно добавить пустой элемент в конец:

```css
div.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
div.flex > div {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0
}
div.flex > span {
    width:30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

но блоки могут быть адаптивными или фиксированной шириной, этот метод не пойдет

Comment: что думаете насчёт нового решения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для случая когда нужно симулировать добавление всего лишь одного элемента (как в примере) можно воспользоваться псевдоклассом для контейнера

```
.flex:after {
  content: "";
  width: 30%;
}
```

Также можно симулировать добавление двух элементов с помощью псевдокласса `before`, а также свойством `order`:

```css
div.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

div.flex > div {
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0
}

.flex:before {
  content: "";
  width: 20%;
  order: 99999;
}

.flex:after {
  content: "";
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Но другого **универсального решения** скорее всего нет, не меняя того, что это flexbox и не используя JavaScript.

Поэтому если предложенное решение не подходит, то задавая пустые элементы у вас всё получится. Их может быть несколько и их можно удалять все или частично из потока отображения с помощью `display: none;` и, если нужно, media queries.

Comment: @Yuri, решение для **конкретного** случая возможно и найдется, в общем случае - вряд ли

Comment: Этот способ понятен, меня интересует, нет-ли более простого и красивого метода, может просто я не нашел какое-то правило..

Comment: @Crantisz, для конкретного случая, вместо space-between можно использовать flex-start и промежутки регулировать с помощью margin. тогда пустые элементы не понадобятся

Comment: @Crantisz а чем этот способ непростой?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, например расчетом количества нужных пустых элементов

Comment: @Grundy, придётся только так, решений больше нет

Comment: @Yuri, почему нет? альтернативу для конкретного примера я выше в комментарии написал

Comment: @Grundy, я это и имел введу )

Comment: @Grundy да было бы красивей если было бы какое-то CSS свойство. Но это мне кажется это намного более простым чем расчёт `margin-right` для последнего элемента в `JavaScript` или табличное расположение элементов. Я имею ввиду что это *относительно* просто.

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил более изящный способ.

Comment: Да, но фактически это тот-же дополнительный элемент, только в профиль.

Comment: @Crantisz тут выигрыш в том, что не надо менять разметку и добавлять элемент(ы) туда.

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличный красивый и лаконичный способ. Применим немного знаний sass и получим замечательный [пример](https://codepen.io/dvnovikov/pen/RBpmQx)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  $gutter: 20px;
  $card-count: 3;
  width: calc(100% / #{$card-count} - #{$gutter} * (#{$card-count} - 1) / #{$card-count} );
  margin-right: $gutter;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  &:nth-of-type(#{$card-count}n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш пример не адаптивный

Comment: Для адаптивности по брейкпоинтам меняйте переменную $card-count