# Как выровнять элементы в последней строке?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

Использую flexbox'ы, есть список элементов, для равномерного растягивания элементов по ширине используется свойство justify-content: space-between; и flex-wrap: wrap; для разделения на строки. Как сделать так чтобы при неполном количестве элементов в строке, элементы выравнивались по левому краю?

Comment: добавь код.....

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли, используя flex с space-between, расположить последнюю строчку с привязкой слева?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602154/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-flex-%d1%81-space-between-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7)

Answer (score 1):

Надо убрать свойство `justify-content:space-between`, чтобы они выравнивались по левому краю.