# Растянуть блоки по ширине Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть ряд блоков, которые должны размещаться по всей ширине родителя по очереди.
Но если этих блоков будет 5шт, то пятый блок будет прижиматься к правой стене(по примеру который добавил ниже).

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.items {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="items"> Item1 </div>
<div class="items"> Item2 </div>
<div class="items"> Item3 </div>
<div class="items"> Item4 </div>
<div class="items"> Item5 </div>
</div>
```

Сам вопрос заключается в том, что нужно что-бы 5й блок вставал по середине, сразу после 4, как это будет если задать `justify-content: start;`, но блоки по прежнему должны растягиваться по всей ширине родителя. В общем условно говоря мне нужно объединить два этих параметра.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли, используя flex с space-between, расположить последнюю строчку с привязкой слева?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602154/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-flex-%d1%81-space-between-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7)

Comment: Не считаю свой вопрос, да и вопрос-дубликат решенными.

Comment: для _flex_ только хаки с доп.элементами, _margin_-ами и т.п. Иначе никак. Только использовать _grid_.

Comment: Отличный вариант про Grid, не дотукал сразу просто взять его. Спасибо. Это действительно будет решением!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать недавно появившийся gap для флексов и не использовать justify-content

```css
 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-content: start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 23px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.items {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="items"> Item1 </div>
<div class="items"> Item2 </div>
<div class="items"> Item3 </div>
<div class="items"> Item4 </div>
<div class="items"> Item5 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Весьма интересное решение, но если блоков будет в ряд 4, а реальных 6, структура будет чуток так себе. Но именно в моём случае это решение.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться и таким приёмом, если заранее известно сколько блоков в одной линии

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.content>*:last-child{
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
}

.content>*:last-child:nth-child(3n){
  display: block;
}

.items {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="items"> Item1 </div>
<div class="items"> Item2 </div>
<div class="items"> Item3 </div>
<div class="items"> Item4 </div>
<div class="items"> Item5 </div>
<div></div>
</div>
```